# Disadvantages of using Texture Cache / Image2D for 2D Arrays?

Tags: optimization, memory, cuda, opencl, textures

When accessing 2D arrays in global memory, using the Texture Cache has many benefits, like filtering and not having to care as much for memory access patterns. The CUDA Programming Guide is only naming one downside:

> However, within the same kernel call, the texture cache is not kept coherent with respect to global memory writes, so that any texture fetch to an address that has been written to via a global write in the same kernel call returns undefined data.

If I don't have a need for that, because I never write to the memory I read from, are there any downsides/pitfalls/problems when using the Texture Cache (or Image2D, as I am working in OpenCL) instead of plain global memory? Are there any cases where I will lose performance by using the Texture Cache?

Answer (score 9):

Textures can be faster, the same speed, or slower than "naked" global memory access. There are no general rules of thumb for predicting performance using textures, as the speed up (or lack of speed up) is determined by data usage patterns within your code and the texture hardware being used.

In the worst case, where cache hit rates are very low, using textures is slower that normal memory access. Each thread has to firstly have a cache miss, then trigger a global memory fetch. The resulting total latency will be higher than a direct read from memory. I almost always write two versions of any serious code I am developing where textures might be useful (one with and one without), and then benchmark them. Often it is possible to develop heuristics to select which version to use based on inputs. CUBLAS uses this strategy extensively.

Comment: +1 for cache miss taking longer, which is what I was asking for. The profiling part I find a bit troubling: you would have to redo that for every piece of hardware that you want to use. Or at least any generation of HW, as I think they are quite different in texture caching. Or do your tests show otherwise?